# Oracle10g XE: Why PLS_INTEGER cannot be a column type

Tags: oracle10g

An invalid datatype is returned when I issue following command:

```
CREATE TABLE msg_info (
   msgcode PLS_INTEGER,
   msgtype VARCHAR2(30),
   msgtext VARCHAR2(2000),
   msgname VARCHAR2(30),
   description VARCHAR2(2000)
   );
```

I discovered it's resulted from **msgcode PLS_INTEGER**, removing this column will make creation successful.

Is it XE restriction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PLS_INTEGER` is **a PL/SQL type only**.  It cannot be used in SQL tables / DDL-at-large.

I think one should declare the column as `NUMBER` type and, when retrieving data, use the `PLS_INTEGER` type at the level of PL/SQL.

See [**Oracle Datatypes**](http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try `BINARY_INTEGER` - it's identical and can be used interchangeably with `PLS_INTEGER`

[link](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/PLS_INTEGER)